# How to decide pulling low on an IC?

Tags: rs485, pulldown, transducer

I am using MAX1484 chip for communicating thru RS485. It is a two way communications with Receiver and Driver built in. If I am to use only the receiver part and I want to disable the driver part, I need to pull low the DE (driver enable) pin. And also the DI pin. What I want to know is whether this pin can be directly shorted to ground or pull to ground via a resistor like 1k or 10k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the DE and DI pins can be connected directly to ground. Just don't connect any *output* pin directly to ground.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know why not to connect output direct to gnd?

Comment: Don't connect any output directly to ground, it's a bad practice. If the output would be high, it would overload the IC and cause a lot of power consumption.

Comment: That make sense ty sir.